# Updated to 14.04 and now my basic terminal commands such as "ls" dont work?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

When I open terminal and then type in ls this is what I get:

[image]

I'm guessing there's an issue with my bashrc or something similar but I can't figure out what to change, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried restarting your system?

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/environment` file now? And the output of `echo $PATH` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this command on your terminal:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

Edit:

Try this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin
```

If this doesn't work too then manually add this command to your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Awesome, timeline or terminal?
And how do I make it permanent?

Comment: Sorry, yeah terminal. You only need to do it once. Now PATH variable in your .bashrc has updated path.

Comment: I assumed I'd only need to do it once also, however, once I open a new terminal it shows the same original message that I posted and again doesn't recognise 'ls'.. any ideas?

Comment: Try this command: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin If this doesn't work too then manually add this command to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: @user206263 Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry had to leave for a bit, when you say manually add to ~/.bashrc does it matter where or how I do that?

Comment: I don't think so. But just to be on safe side add it at end of file. As to how you can open .bashrc with any editor.

Comment: Perfect, added it to the end and it works! 
The very first line with "awk: 1: unexpected character '.'", still shows up but it doesn't seem to be having an effect

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. For your awk problem look at other answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'` should be a good indication for what's gone wrong here. Something has pooped over your command line start-up scripts and because it's breaking out, it's not adding your path correctly.

I'd look for any instance of `awk` in `~/.bashrc` but you'll need to call things with their full paths:

```
/bin/grep awk /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

If you find something, `/usr/bin/nano` is where the Nano editor lives.